# HTML load CSV and make editable Table

Tags: html, csv

is it possible to load a CSV-file to a table in HTML, make it editable and save it at the same time or with a button to the same same CSV file without installing additional software. Only with HTML?

I am looking for a solution with HTML because i want to load this on several screens and make it editable for more users (not atthe same time)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No for that you need some JavaScript to interact with browser file APIs or send the request to save data on backend.

Comment: Ah ok. Can you explain me or give me plz an example how this can be done with java?

Comment: https://www.js-tutorials.com/jquery-tutorials/reading-csv-file-using-jquery/ for example, but do the research.

Comment: Consider closing the question by marking the answer as correct.